# HTTP header error using the Python SDK for Azure

Tags: python, linux, azure

I am starting with Microsoft Azure SDK for Python (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python), but I have problems.

I am using Scientific Linux and I have installed the SDK for Python 3.4 following the next steps:

(instead of the SDK directory)
python setup.py install

after that I created a simple script just to test the connection:

```
from azure.storage import BlobService

blob_service = BlobService(account_name='thename', account_key='Mxxxxxxx3w==' )

blob_service.create_container('testcontainer')

for i in blob_service.list_containers():
        print(i.name)
```

following this documentation:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2013/04/17/how-to-interact-with-windows-azure-blob-storage-from-linux-using-python.aspx
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/#large-blobs

but is not working, I always receive the same error:

> python3 test.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/azure-0.9.0-py3.4.egg/azure/storage/storageclient.py", line 143, in _perform_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/azure-0.9.0-py3.4.egg/azure/storage/storageclient.py", line 132, in _perform_request_worker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/azure-0.9.0-py3.4.egg/azure/http/httpclient.py", line 247, in perform_request
azure.http.HTTPError: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    blob_service.create_container('testcontainer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/azure-0.9.0-py3.4.egg/azure/storage/blobservice.py", line 192, in create_container
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/azure-0.9.0-py3.4.egg/azure/__init__.py", line 905, in _dont_fail_on_exist
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/azure-0.9.0-py3.4.egg/azure/storage/blobservice.py", line 189, in create_container
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/azure-0.9.0-py3.4.egg/azure/storage/storageclient.py", line 150, in _perform_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/azure-0.9.0-py3.4.egg/azure/storage/__init__.py", line 889, in _storage_error_handler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/azure-0.9.0-py3.4.egg/azure/__init__.py", line 929, in _general_error_handler
azure.WindowsAzureError: Unknown error (The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code><Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:b37c5584-0001-002b-24b8-c2c245000000
Time:2014-11-19T14:54:38.9378626Z</Message><HeaderName>x-ms-version</HeaderName><HeaderValue>2012-02-12</HeaderValue></Error>
```

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact same issue. I believe it's a library bug, but the author/s haven't had their say yet.

It looks like the response states the version, but it's actually giving you the header that's wrong. Its value should be "2014-02-14", you can do the fix shown in https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/pull/289 .

Hopefully this will be fixed and nobody will ever read this answer. Cheers!